# Stuck on basic class inheritance in Python (Learn Python The Hard Way ex42)

Tags: python

I'm working on this lesson about classes:

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex42.html

I have about an 80-90% understanding of how it all works and I'm playing around with the code to make it do other things and Im trying to get a sentence to print out that says the following:

'Mary has a cat that is called Satan'

My understanding is that Python will inherit from all 3 classes below to print out this statement but I cant get it to print what I want only this:

'Mary  has a  <**main**.Cat object at 0x000000000569B0B8>  called <**main**.Cat object at 0x000000000569B0B8>'

so it is printing out the string and then the actual Python objects and not what they are right?

This is the code below, sorry its a lot and has some other things going on in it but I guess I need to show all for people to understand whats going on?

This is the line Im stuck on:

def has_pet(self):
        print self.name, " has a ", self.pet, " called", satan

I cant see what Im doing wrong :/

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, species):
        self.species = species

    def print_animal(self):
        print "This is a ", self.species, ", it croaks"

class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, dog_name, species):
    ## Dog has a name that is name
       self.dog_name = dog_name
       self.species = species

    def print_name(self):
        print "The pet is called...", self.dog_name

    def print_species(self):
        print "Your pet is a ", self.species

    def ask_dog(self):
        print "What kind of dog do you have?"
        choice = raw_input("> ")
        print "Oh wow, I have a ", choice, " too"

yourDog = Dog("Bob", "dog")
yourAnimal = Animal('frog')
yourAnimal.print_animal()
yourDog.print_name()
yourDog.print_species()
yourDog.ask_dog()

class Cat(Animal):

    def __init__(self, name):
        ## Cat has a name that is name
        self.name = name
        self.species = 'Cat' #is this redundant?

    def print_name(self):
        print "The cat is called ", self.name

your_cat = Cat('Tigger')
your_cat.print_name()

class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        ## Person has a name that is name
        self.name = name

        ## Person has-a pet of some kind
        self.pet = satan

    def has_pet(self):
        print self.name, " has a ", self.pet, " called", satan #stuck here

## satan is-a Cat
## Cat is-aanimal
## animal is-a object
satan = Cat("Satan")
satan.print_name()


## mary is-a Person
## Person is-a object
who = Person("Mary")
who.has_pet()
```

Comment: I suspect you might want to [overload `__str__`](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/operatoroverloading1.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you try to print out an object in python, python internally calls its `__str__` method, if an `__str__` method is not defined directly in your class, then it tries to take from one of the super classes , by default if no super class is specified `object` class becomes the superclass for your class, and it has the `__str__` implementation that prints out like - `<main.Cat object at 0x000000000569B0B8>` .

Example showing that -

```
>>> object.__str__(object())
'<object object at 0x003E1490>'
```

Now, this is the reason you get the `<main.Cat ....>` , I believe you do not want to print out the object directly, instead you should access the name variable in the object and print that out and access the `species` variable and print that out.

Example the line having issue would change to -

```
print self.name, " has a ", self.pet.species, " called", self.pet.name
```